# Retrofit custom call and callback

Tags: android, http, request, retrofit2

I have a json schema for all of my api responses like;

```
{
 "data":"objects",
 "status":"success",
 "message":"message"
}
```

I want to use retrofit as http client but i dont want to repeat `response.body.getData()` in the callback.Can i implement it as generic form?
 and beside i need to have one pipeline for all of my api calls to handle responses and errors in one place and delegate the specific data to to the one is calling it.I have tried extending Call and Callback classes.thanks

Comment: Show the code. What have you tried?

Comment: I think you should create Basepresenter or baseactivity for all activity class and then create the method in base class.